# Padding not visible inside div block?

Tags: css

Please check the [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bhawan0407/6uhxvvb4/) and tell why padding is not visible inside div container?

```css
body {
  background-color: #B8C4BB;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.section_two {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10 px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    Change the value of the color property to see how it changes the text color of this element.
  </div>
  <div class="section_two">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, alias, aliquid fugiat dolorem repudiandae quidem. Molestiae illum pariatur officia voluptate cumque. Necessitatibus earum consequuntur explicabo minus ratione mollitia illum nam.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using any css framework?

Comment: Thanks @Wasi Ahmad for formatting it. I am new here so not aware of these formatting options.

Comment: No simple css @ChandraShekher

Comment: you have'nt used padding on container

Comment: By adding p tag after div class="section_two" , I am getting the padding , but why this p tag is required ?

Comment: p tag is paragraph tag, used to display content as paragraphs, and margin on top and bottom not padding is be because of the browser's pre defined styles.

Comment: to remove unnecessary padding or margin issues you need to use CSS resets to maintain consistency across browsers http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/   ... read here for more info

Answer (score 3):

You have only typing mistake.

```
use padding property

like: padding: 10px;
insteade of: 10 px;
```

See [Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6uhxvvb4/1/)

Comment: if this answer is help full to you then please approve..!!

Answer (score 1):

Your css is like following:

```
.section_two {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10 px;
}
```

Value for padding is invalid. It should be as `padding: 10px`. Without space between `10` and `px`

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you have put a space between 10 and px. It should be like following code.

```
.section_two {
   border: 2px solid red;
   padding: 50px;
}
```